# How can I right click on an image in Finder and copy its pixel data?

Tags: finder, graphics, copy-paste

I'm using Mac OS X Mountain Lion. I frequently open many image files and copy its pixel data thereafter paste into Photoshop.

So I wonder how can I right click on an image in Finder and copy its pixel data? Is there any app or Services (using Automator) can do this trick? It would help me save tons of my time working with images.

Thanks for any help out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to copy the pixel data, but you *can* just drag & drop the file directly into Photoshop to achieve the same thing.

This works with most image editing and publishing applications I've used (including things like Powerpoint/Keynote, Word/Pages, as well as all the usual image editors).